# pygame - collisions: teleporting and "sliding" issue

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, game-physics

I've made a couple of posts abut pygame collisions, and here is one more. I apologize for the "spam" of posts, but these bugs are strange to me. Also, I'm working with a group, so I'm not sure if the problem lies in the code I've made or in the code that others have made.

That being said, here is the link to our github: https://github.com/drexel-game-devs/Project_Folder

All the code I'm referencing is inside the Code folder, under Player Assets.

I'm responsible for making the Physics_Engine class, which is where collisions are handled. The function is called in the Player_Assets class, where the Player class is stored. Right now, collisions are detected and handled in a glitchy way. If I approach an object from the right, the player will stop for a certain amount of time and then teleport through the object. Approaching an object from the top is even stranger: the player will "slide" off the object, and creep down it's left/right side, and then fall off the object's "bottom".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it seems you add some value to some variable (which can change position) when player collide object - but you should't. When this variable is enough big (bigger then collided object) player position (plus this variable) gives you position on other side of object.Maybe you add `speed` to `x` when player collide object but you correct position only to draw it.

Answer (score 0):

I see big problem in `handle_collision`

You change somewhere `x` and `y` **at the same time** and then

1. you get collisions - `spritecollide()`
2. if you move `left/right` you change `x`

And here is the problem.

`spritecollide()` gives you **all collisions** - `left/right` and `top/bottom`.

It may happen that player collide only `top/bottom` but you will tread it as `left/right` collision (and you will slide player to `left/right` side).

-

You have to do:

1. change **only** `x`
2. get collisions - it gives only `left/right` collisions
3. if you move `left/right` you change `x`
4. change **only** `y`
5. get collisions - it gives only `top/bottom` collisions
6. if you move `top/bottom` you change `y`